# What does "in using" mean?

Tags: gerunds, prepositional-phrases

A sentence I found has the phrase "current trends in using business applications".

What does *in using* mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In using* is not a constituent—a distinct part of the sentence.

A preposition phrase headed by *in* is the usual way of telling what kind of *trend* you are talking about. For instance, we speak of

> trends **in** fashion
> trends **in** music
> trends **in** economics
> trends **in** marketing
> trends **in** programming

Note that last two trends have *-ing* words as the object of the preposition *in*. When an *-ing* form is used this way it is called a *gerund*—it acts as a verb and as a noun at the same time.

- It can act like a noun in acting as the object of a preposition or a verb, or as the subject of a verb:

  > I live by writing. Writing is my profession.  I enjoy writing.
- It can act like a verb in taking its own subject (expressed usually as a possessive, but in some circumstances by an objective pronoun) and its own objects:

  > My writing answers gives me great pleasure.

In the sentence fragment you quote, *using business applications* is a gerund phrase—a gerund plus its object in this case—acting as the object of the preposition *in*.  You might paraphrase the sense thus:

> trends in *how business applications are used*

Comment: "trends in how business applications are used" oh now it makes sense :) thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

It just means the same as 'while using' or 'in the use of'. So to rephrase your sentence:

**state current trends in the use of business applications**

So it's not the trends in the applications themselves but how people are using them to accomplish their goals.

Comment: I am not exactly clear can you explain it more properly?